# how to make a fixed-number-of-words-search dynamic in Coldfusion/MySql?

Tags: mysql, string, search, coldfusion, parameters

I'm trying to upgrade a Coldfusion8/MySQL site. The site has a complex search which, (among other criteria) takes text strings and searches these in a keyword table.

I don't want to do a FULLTEXT search, because the full query has a lot of extra conditions. What I'm looking for is to make the following more **"dynamic"**, that is not limit myself to xy words and thereby maybe shortening this a bit (the full search has plenty of blocks like this).

So, say I have a search string like

```
I'm looking for something
```

I'm currently doing this:

```
<!--- params --->
<cfparam name="s01" default="">
<cfparam name="s02" default="">
<cfparam name="s03" default="">    
<cfparam name="s04" default="">
<cfparam name="s05" default="">

<!--- get length of search string --->
<cfset howManyWords = ListLen(textSearch," ")>

<!--- assign words to params --->
<cfif howManyWords gt 0><cfset s01 = trim(ListGetAt(textSearch, 1," "))></cfif>
<cfif howManyWords gt 1><cfset s02 = trim(ListGetAt(textSearch, 2," "))></cfif>
<cfif howManyWords gt 2><cfset s03 = trim(ListGetAt(textSearch, 3," "))></cfif>
<cfif howManyWords gt 3><cfset s04 = trim(ListGetAt(textSearch, 4," "))></cfif>
<cfif howManyWords gt 4><cfset s05 = trim(ListGetAt(textSearch, 5," "))></cfif>
```

In my **search query**, I'm matching the search strings to three database fields:

```
...
<cfif textSearch neq "">
    <cfif s01 neq "">AND (a.textSearch LIKE "%#s01#%" OR a.textSearch_xl LIKE "%#s01#%" OR a.ean = "#s01#")</cfif>
    <cfif s02 neq "">AND (a.textSearch LIKE "%#s02#%" OR a.textSearch_xl LIKE "%#s02#%" OR a.ean = "#s02#")</cfif>
    <cfif s03 neq "">AND (a.textSearch LIKE "%#s03#%" OR a.textSearch_xl LIKE "%#s03#%" OR a.ean = "#s03#")</cfif>
    <cfif s04 neq "">AND (a.textSearch LIKE "%#s04#%" OR a.textSearch_xl LIKE "%#s04#%" OR a.ean = "#s04#")</cfif>
    <cfif s05 neq "">AND (a.textSearch LIKE "%#s05#%" OR a.textSearch_xl LIKE "%#s05#%" OR a.ean = "#s05#")</cfif>
</cfif>
...
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to make this more dynamic, for example with a loop, so I'm not stuck with 5 words? How would I preset the *param* values in this case?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you considered using Lucene/Solr?  I've not done it myself, but fairly sure they can be connected to a MySQL database and will handle all this word stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be checking this out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just explode the search term by looping over it as a list within the query, you should also be using query parameters to prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
<cfloop list="#textSearch#" index="word" delimiters=" ">
  AND (
    a.textSearch LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cfsql_varchar" value="%#word#%"> 
    OR a.textSearch_xl LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cfsql_varchar" value="%#word#%">  
    OR a.ean = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cfsql_varchar" value="#word#"> 
  )
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I thought, too. No need to declare all the params up front. As for SQLinjection/query params.... I have about a gazillion fields to update :-). Hadn't done it on this page yet. Still wondering why the original devs did not do it in the first place.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a CF extension for CFBuilder that will highlight all queries without params for you.

Comment: Not just CFBuilder, [qpscanner](http://hybridchill.com/projects/qpscanner.html) is a standalone application, and there's a (generic) Eclipse plugin too. Actually it looks like the [CFB extension](http://qpscannerextension.riaforge.org/) is still using v0.7.0 which is pretty old - [the latest 0.7.5 version](https://github.com/boughtonp/qpscanner/tree/rc0.7.5) has several bug fixes and speed improvements over that.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a simple regex using using alternation and then use MySQL's [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator. You'd want something like this in the SQL:

```
and (a.textSearch regexp 'a|b|c|...' or a.textSearch_xl regexp 'a|b|c|...' or a.ean regexp 'a|b|c|...')
```

where `a`, `b`, `c`, ... are the things you're searching for. I don't know the ColdFushion side of things though but building the regex should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: You'd want to escape possible regex special characters in the strings with this approach or you could get some strange results, for example `A+` could match 'A' or 'AAAAA'

Comment: @PhilParsons: I thought that would be obvious. You have to escape things with LIKE as well since `%` and `_` have special meanings.

Comment: @muistooshort - I will give this some thought, too. Although... regex is not my forte...

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool in this case, but (for reference) if you did want to try it you'd want something like `<cfset EscapedText = OrigText.replaceAll('[$^*()+\[\]{}.?\\|]','\\$0').replaceAll('\s+','|') />` to first escape the relevant metacharacters and then replace all spaces with pipes. _(Assuming OrigText is already trimmed, if not, that would need doing.)_